# Set Google Tag Manager variable anonymizeIp by cookie value

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Using the Google Tag Manager script (not Analytics or gatag.js) and would like to be able to only set anonymizeIp to `true` whenever the user accepts cookies.

Is this possible? From what I've read, setting the variable in Google Tag Manager means it is always set to false or true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable in GTM to track cookie acceptance like so (make sure you check the undefined and null conditions to "false":
[image]

Then in your GA settings variable or GA tag, just reference the cookie variable: [image]